# How to sort the strings as what I want?

Tags: sorting, icu

I'm following [this demo](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/collation.html)

Here is strings..

```
a
Aaa
áa
Aa
A
á
```

I want to order

```
a
A
Aa
Aaa
á
áa
```

But the `ICU` demo works for

```
a
A
á
Aa
áa
Aaa
```

How do I apply it to correct sort as what I want?

Comment: Show us what you have tried?

Comment: Dude, what? Could you explain it a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

**You can use `.localeCompare()` in Javascript to implement the compare function in `.sort()`, there you can pass in any [locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) of your choice.**

```js
let stringToBeSorted = "a Aaa áa Aa A á";

let sortedString = stringToBeSorted.split(" ").sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.localeCompare(obj2)).join(" ");

console.log(sortedString);
```